# Using Axios POST to ASP.Net WEB API 2 with VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, axios

I am having trouble reading my Axios json data inside my VB.NET Web API 2 controller. I send it like

```
var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      }

  let url = 'https://.azurewebsites.net/api/SavePMIDdata/'
  axios.post(url, {
      params: {
        pmids: PMIDList,
        memberID: memberID
      }
    }, {
      'headers': headers
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      resultElement.innerHTML = generateSuccessHTMLOutput(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      resultElement.innerHTML = generateErrorHTMLOutput(error);
    });
}
```

My controller information in my WebAPIConfig is:

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="ActionApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}"
    )
```

and my Controller class is :

```
 Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal data As JToken) As String
```

and I have tried:

```
  Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal data As string) As String
```

and

```
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal data As objJSON ) As String
```

with

```
   Public Class objJSON          
        Public Property pmids As String
        Public Property memberID As String
    End Class
```

When I send it I get a Status 200 and if I put in a hard coded return value I get that but if I try the read the params being sent I get a null.  I don't think I reading them correctly.

If I try to do
         Dim json As JObject = JObject.Parse(data)
I get back

```
"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: s"
```

If this is a duplicate question please send me to it because I can't find it.  I've been searching for three days.  I've come across a few things close but I can't get VB to work. I'm trying to convert old .asmx code over to a newer structure.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of tweaking I have now created what works.  I'm not 100% sure that this is a best practice and would love input from anyone that can give me input.

First I changed my

```
axios.post(url, {
      params: {
        pmids: PMIDList,
        memberID: memberID
      }
    }, {
      'headers': headers
    })
```

to

axios.post(url, {
        pmids: PMIDList,
        memberID: memberID
    }, {
      'headers': headers
    })

I took out the params:{}

Next in my controller I used:

```
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As objJSON) As String
            Dim x = value.pmids.ToString
            return (x)
End Function
```

It now returns the pmids string that was sent in the axios POST. I'm happy and can now move on.  If there is a best practice standard I'd love to learn.